# Let me add references to print articles

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Right now I can only reference articles that are available online. I'd really like to add references to books I've co-authored and articles that I've written for tech magazines.

Comment: What the point of references when the reader can't access what is referenced?

Comment: What do you mean by "reference"? Wouldn't you just say "...as written in Article X, available in Journal Y, June 2011"?

Comment: Yes, I mean what Ether was saying. To clarify: I want to be able to add _print_ articles and _print_ books to my profile. Those are things that possibly are not mentioned anywhere online. Right now I can only add articles to my profile that have an URL (= that are available online, like a blog post).